# Console I/O in Common Lisp

Tags: input, lisp, common-lisp, console-application

In Common Lisp, I am writing a console application. I've finished most of the code, but two critical pieces are still confusing me.

1. How to read a key from the input and get the ascii code for it.
2. How to display an ascii character, without special formatting or newline.

On the second, I've tried:

```
(print (code-char 69))
```

Which displays:

```
#\E
```

But I just want it to display a plain:

```
E
```

On the first, I've had no luck at all.

If it helps, I am running clisp on Linux and OS X. Thanks!

Comment: Common Lisp differentiates between the character and the encoding, fyi. #\E is the character. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [read-char](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_cha.htm) and [write-char](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_cha.htm) in the [streams CLHS chapter](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_stream.htm). READ-CHAR reads a character. Portable Common Lisp does not have the capabilities to read 'keys', but it can read characters from a stream.

For getting the code of a character see [char-code](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_stream.htm).

Answer (score 1):

to get a plain "E", execute

```
(princ (code-char 69))
```

Comment: Nice. This is shorter than what I did initially: (write-char (code-char 69) *standard-output*)